# Dynamically pivot to fixed number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the structure of my data

```
Name       TransID       Amount

Joe        123           56
Joe        124           55
Joe        125           58
Tom        126           31
Tom        127           48
```

I have a requirement to report from this data in the below format

```
Name      Amount1        Amount2

Joe       56             55
Joe       58
Tom       31             48
```

Joe has three Amounts in the original data set but I need a fixed number of columns (two) in the view. Therefore, the third Amount for Joe is inserted as a new record in the view. Is it possible to achieve this as a stored procedure or creating a view.

Comment: I am just curious what was your original need to show data like this?

Comment: @RezaRahmati  I understand that this a very poor way to display data. But I have been asked to reproduce a 10 year old Excel "report" in a view.

Comment: Is there any limit on the number of amounts per person?

Comment: so, you always want the lowest transId for a name grouped with the next lowest, and then a new line with it's lowest and the next lowest if exists after that?

Comment: @RezaRahmati There is no hard maximum limit for the number of amounts.

Comment: @xQbert The order does not really matter. Just that it should be able to insert a new row when there are more than 2 amounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break the problems into smaller steps. These are the steps that I would take:

- Use [ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

  ```
  Name       TransID       Amount    Row_Number

  Joe        123           56        1
  Joe        124           55        2
  Joe        125           58        3
  Tom        126           31        1 
  Tom        127           48        2
  ```
- Subtract 1.

  ```
  Name       TransID       Amount    RowNumberStartingWith0

  Joe        123           56        0
  Joe        124           55        1
  Joe        125           58        2
  Tom        126           31        0 
  Tom        127           48        1
  ```
- Divide it by 2, get the result of the division and the remainder modulo 2:

  ```
  Name       TransID       Amount    Result  Remainder

  Joe        123           56        0       0
  Joe        124           55        0       1
  Joe        125           58        1       0
  Tom        126           31        0       0 
  Tom        127           48        0       1
  ```
- Drop the `TransID` column. The remainder is always 0 or 1, so you can pivot on it:

  ```
  Name       Result  AmountForRemainder0 AmountForRemainder1

  Joe        0       56                  55
  Joe        1       58
  Tom        0       31                  48
  ```
- Now you drop the `Result` column and rename your columns:

  ```
  Name      Amount1        Amount2

  Joe       56             55
  Joe       58
  Tom       31             48
  ```
- Profit.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this and let me know .Check with other sample data also.I am getting the desire output.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,TransID INT
    ,Amount INT
    )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ('Joe',123,56)
    ,('Joe',124,55)
    ,('Joe',125,58)
    ,('Tom',126,31)
    ,('Tom',127,48)
    ,('Tom',128,89)
    ,('Tom',129,90)
    ,('Joe',130,68);

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY amount
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,(
            SELECT amount
            FROM cte
            WHERE rn = 1
                AND NAME = a.NAME
            ) [Amount1]
        ,(
            SELECT amount
            FROM cte
            WHERE rn = 2
                AND NAME = a.NAME
            ) [Amount2]
        ,rn
    FROM cte A
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT b.NAME
        ,a.amount
        ,isnull(c.amount, 0)
        ,a.rn
    FROM CTE1 B

    INNER JOIN CTE A ON a.NAME = b.NAME
        AND a.rn % 2 <> 0
        AND a.rn > 1
        AND b.rn <> a.rn
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT Amount
        FROM CTE C
        WHERE NAME = b.NAME
            AND rn % 2 = 0
            AND rn > 2
        ) c

    )
SELECT *
FROM cte1
```